# error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator%' in c++

Tags: c++

Just started programing in C++ a few weeks ago and I encountered this problem:

```
float a,i,b,c,d,e,f;
cin>>a;
cin>>c;
if(c%2==0)
{
    d=c;
    e=1;
}
else
{
    d=0;
    e=0;
}

for (i=2;i<=a;i++)
{
     cin>>b;
     if(b%2==0)
     {
         d=d+b;
         e=e+1;
     }
}
f=d/e;
if(e==0)
    cout<<"0";
else
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<f;
```

Ideally, the program should display on the screen the number "f" representing the arithmetic average.

Comment: The modulo operator `%` is defined only for integer operands. This applies to C, C++ and AFAIK Java. Some other programming languages allow the left-hand operand to be decimal though. 2.532 % 2 would yield 0.532. The fundamental problem is when the right-hand operand is not integer

Comment: As the error message says, you can't use the `%` operator on floating-point types.

Answer (score 8):

The % operator is not defined for real numbers - you want the fmod() function declared in `<cmath>`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod